# "Invalid Handle" Create CGBitmapContext

Tags: xamarin.ios, cgbitmapcontext

I've got a problem with the CGBitmapcontext.
I get en error while creating the CGBitmapContext with the message "invalid Handle".

Here is my code:

```
var previewContext = new CGBitmapContext(null, (int)ExportedImage.Size.Width, (int)ExportedImage.Size.Height, 8, (int)ExportedImage.Size.Height * 4,                                                    CGColorSpace.CreateDeviceRGB(), CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst);
```

Thank you;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is because you are passing null to the first parameter. The CGBitmapContext is for drawing directly into a memory buffer. The first parameter in all the overloads of the constructor is (Apple docs):

> *data* 
>   A pointer to the destination in memory where the drawing is to be rendered. The size of this memory block should be at least
>   (bytesPerRow*height) bytes.

In MonoTouch, we get two overloads that accept a byte[] for convenience. So you should use it like this:

```
int bytesPerRow = (int)ExportedImage.Size.Width * 4; // note that bytes per row should 
    //be based on width, not height.
byte[] ctxBuffer = new byte[bytesPerRow * (int)ExportedImage.Size.Height];
var previewContext = 
    new CGBitmapContext(ctxBuffer, (int)ExportedImage.Size.Width, 
    (int)ExportedImage.Size.Height, 8, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapFlags);
```

Comment: Thanks, though this behavior is different to what apple docs say:  `data', if non-NULL, points to a block
   of memory at least `bytesPerRow * height' bytes. If `data' is NULL, the
   data for context is allocated automatically and freed when the context is
   deallocated.

Comment: Important point! Your app will crash randomly if you allow your ctxBuffer to be garbage collected before you stop using context! I had context variable on class level, while ctxBuffer was local variable in the function creating context. App was crashing until I moved ctxBuffer to class level. Beware!

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if the `width` or `height` parameters passed into the method have a value of 0.