# Getting an image from a sample buffer

Tags: xamarin.ios, screen-capture, avcapturesession, cgbitmapcontext, base-address

I am trying to capture a screen shot on the ipad while the camera is on. My code looks exactly like the AVCaptureFrames from the Xamarin MonoTouch  sample:

[image]

For some reason, though, I keep getting an Invalid Handler Exception. I have looked at other questions similar to mine, such as:

[CGBitmapContext in MonoTouch throws invalid handle exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281658/cgbitmapcontext-in-monotouch-throws-invalid-handle-exception) and ["Invalid Handle" Create CGBitmapContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118388/invalid-handle-create-cgbitmapcontext)

But their solutions aren't solving my similar problem. My issue doesn't stem from a sending in null or because my memory is too large. I'm not sending in a null value and I checked my memory usage through the xcode allocations instrument and my memory usage doesn't explode; it only adds 400KB at the most.

Comment: Could you please replace the image with the actual source code ? also can you edit your question to add the exact exception text/stacktrace this gets you ? thanks